# How to send string from activity to fragment using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, bundle

when i try to run this code, it show me an exception and it is "nullPointer exception". I can't find the bug of this code, can anyone help me to fix that bug please? my code is blow please help me to fix it.

here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    EditText testInputTV;
    Button send;
    Bundle bundle;
    String welcome ="Welcome";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        testInputTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testInput);

        send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        bundle =new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("welcome", welcome);
        FragmentOne fragobj = new FragmentOne();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


}
```

my Fragment class

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    String storeText;
    private Bundle bundle;

    public FragmentOne() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        storeText = bundle.getString("welcome");
        Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(),storeText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return view;
    }


}
```

Error text in Logcat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: What line is throwing this exception?

Comment: Change `adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");` to `adapter.addFragment(fragobj, "ONE");`.

Comment: storeText = bundle.getString("welcome"); this line make the exception

Comment: well It's worked properly. :) but only for fixed String. For dynamic data which changed on runtime, what should be the proper solution. Note: in runtime the send string return null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new fragment instead of using the one you made and set the arguments to:

```
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
```

Change this to:

```
adapter.addFragment(fragobj, "ONE");
```

Also it is recommended to use Abstract Factory design pattern with `newInstance` method when instantiating a fragment, something like:

```
public static FragmentOne newInstance(Bundle b) {
    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
    fragment.setArguments(b);

    return fragment;
}
```

And then create your fragment like:

```
FragmentOne fragobj = FragmentOne.newInstance(bundle);
```

And in this line you're setting arguments and creating it as well.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You can do `getArguments()` whenever and then put the new data and then set arguments again. What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
```

as you are creating a new object instead of old one with bundle object.

Try below code:

```
adapter.addFragment(fragobj, "ONE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with these lines :

```
 FragmentOne fragobj = new FragmentOne();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
```

You are creating a new fragment while calling add fragment (not using the one which you have used for setting arguments)

Change to :

```
 FragmentOne fragobj = new FragmentOne();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
adapter.addFragment(fragobj, "ONE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
```

To:

```
adapter.addFragment(fragobj, "ONE");
```

You are creating new instance of `FragmentOne` but `Bundle` is seted to `fragobj`.